# Why and how do we get NH4NO3 when reacting very dilute HNO3 with Zn?

Tags: oxidation-state

From Russian Wikipedia's [article](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B7%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0) on nitric acid:

[image]

It's clear that as we decrease the concentration of nitric acid, we get more and more reduced nitrogen: in $\ce{NO2}$, the oxidation state of N is ($\mathrm{+4}$), then it goes to zero in $\ce{N2}$ (when we use $\mathrm{10\%}$ strong $\ce{HNO3}$).

But why all of a sudden we get $\ce{NH4NO3}$? In $\ce{NH4}$, the oxidation of $\ce{N}$ is ($\mathrm{-3}$), in $\ce{NO3}$, the oxidation state is ($\mathrm{+5}$). So the overall oxidation increases by $\mathrm{2}$.

I wonder how this ammonium nitrate is generated, i.e. where the ammonium ion evolves from.

---

P.S. [Got an answer on Socratic](https://socratic.org/questions/why-and-how-do-we-get-nh4no3-when-reacting-very-dilute-hno3-with-zn).

Comment: Ammonium ion is generated from $\ce{HNO3}$ in full accordance with the previous trend which you correctly summarized as follows: as we decrease the concentration of nitric acid, we get more and more reduced nitrogen.

Comment: Very well you got answer for your question. Here, best thing is that you can answer your own question. So, feel free to write that here.